# Drop down menu isnt working with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
timeout = 50
driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain")
selection = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('select_symbol'))
time.sleep(2)
selection.select_by_index(3)
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

I need to get the call option total from the table on the site for each option in the dropdown menu, but the selected option doesn't load and the table doesn't load. Pls help

Comment: I don't think so it would be easy to do that since the app has implemented ways to check if the user is hitting using some automated softwares. After a couple of tries you will start getting `403` errors.

Comment: @demouser123 : There's always a workaround in computer science.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, `Webapps` **do not** show `desired web element` while handled by `automation software/tool such as Selenium.`

The workaround I have come to know know is that, in this kind of situation, we need to pass `Arrow_down key using automated software and using JS` (could be `Select` `class` also **depends** on the `website`), we can let the application show all the options.

### Using Selenium this is how drop down looks :- (Basically it does not show the options).

[image]

Now when we use the below code that has Arrow down keys implemented :

**Code :-**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

select = Select(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "equity_optionchain_select"))))
select.select_by_visible_text("NIFTY")

ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).key_up(Keys.ARROW_UP).perform()
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('select_symbol').selectedIndex = '3';")
```

## Using Selenium this is how it looks now :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

how about using

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select_symbol"]/option[3]').click()
```

It is easy to only change `option['number'].`

Comment: The issue here is that, he is not able to see drop down menu using Selenium.